# validate user input by length in Python

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x, user-input

I have some code:

```
def GetPlayerName():
  print()
  PlayerName = input('Please enter your name: ')
  print()
  return PlayerName
```

How can I keep asking for the player's name until they enter a name that is more than one character long, and tell them they must enter a valid name if they leave the field blank?

I tried

```
def GetPlayerName():
  print()
  PlayerName = input('Please enter your name: ')
  print()
  return PlayerName
  while len(PlayerName) < 1:
    print("You must enter a name!")
```

but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Well, it could be helpful if you'd show us your solution so we can say _why_ it doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding the last edit: How would you expect the value of `PlayerName` to change in the loop?

Comment: Pretty close to being a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: @jme I disagree. That question is about error handling.

Comment: @Iplodman Read the section titled: "Implementing Your Own Validation Rules". Swap the requirement that the input is in all caps for the requirement that the length is greater than one, and you have this question.

Comment: @jme Ah, I see your point! ;P

Answer (score 3):

Use a while loop to get the `input` repetitively:

```
def get_player_name():
    print()
    player_name = ""
    while len(player_name) <= 1: 
        player_name = input('Please enter your name: ')
        print()
    return player_name
```

The way you are currently using it, you use the `while` statement to only print the error message.

PS: I've converted your variable names etc to small_caps_format because that is what [PEP recommends](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: The question wanted to ensure `len(player_name) > 1`, so you'll need `<=` rather than `<` in the `while`'s predicate. Also, it would be nice to print an error message if the user inputs a bad name. It can be more succinct to do that if you use the `while True` idiom.

Comment: @jme thanks for the suggestions, made changes regarding the `len > 1`, As for the other, there is already another answer for the `while True` idiom..

Answer (score 2):

```
def GetPlayerName():
    print()

    while True:
        PlayerName = input('Please enter your name: ')

        if len(PlayerName) > 1:
            break
        print("Your name is too short! :c")

    print()
    return PlayerName
```

One solution amongst others, and doesn't require any variables outside of the while loop. As mentioned by @jme, the error message is rather easy to print with this solution. The issue with your code is that:

1. Your while loop is after the `return` statement is called, so it's affectively rendered mute.
2. Your while loop is infinite-- it doesn't give the user a chance to re-try!

Comment: A single line can be added to this solution to print an error message on invalid input. The other solutions require a bit more work. That might be an advantage worth mentioning in your answer.

Comment: Whats the point of the while True if you don't have a continue in it ? That way you get big problems when working on bigger programs. But i like your style tho..